# How to allow user to select an existing database or create a new one?

Tags: sql-server

We have a desktop application built with WinForms in 4.0 framework. A single user can install the application and use a local SQLExpress installation. Or, the SQLExpress can be on another machine on the network. We want to give users ability to create new database(which will execute a sql script which will create the required structure) on any server instance. Is there a control which we can used to accomplish this? Or, what are the ways to accomplish the aim?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using an ORM (such as nHibernate)- then these abilities come out-of-the-box.
otherwise- you can write stored procedures that build the desired database.
this is a little more tricky, but possible.
[here](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/sqlfundamentals_2.htm) is a good start on DDL.

Comment: ...subject to permissions to create a database which is at the server level. A stored proc allows you to control how the database is created (paths, collation etc) and to provide scope-limited privilege escalation

Comment: absolutely right. that was what I meant by 'a little more tricky' :)